# C# - DotNetBar - Visual Studio - Testing tint colors?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, for-loop, struct

I would like to experiment with the tint color of the dotnetbar style manager. There are quite a few colors in C#'s System.Drawing.Color, so I would like to make a simple application with a button that steps through each color.

I would to do some kind of foreach loop or something along those lines, but it says that System.Drawing.Color is a type. I'm new to C#, is there even a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're referring to the named colors defined in the [`System.Drawing.Color` structure](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.aspx) via static properties. They're all listed in the documentation, but as you've discovered, there's no intuitive way of looping through them.

Instead, you'll need to use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy.aspx) (in simplified terms, code that can see itself) in order to get at them. Basically what you're doing is getting a collection of all the public, static properties within the `Color` type (which, in this case, just happen to be the named colors), and then looping through each of those.

For example, you might use code like this (warning, untested!):

```
var colorType = typeof(System.Drawing.Color);
var staticProperties = colorType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
var colors = staticProperties.Select(prop => (Color)prop.GetValue(null, null));
foreach (Color clr in colors)
{
    // Test the color...
}
```

Comment: There's no getType method of Color :(

Comment: @Walkerneo: Whoops; try that.

Answer (score 1):

[Color.FromArgb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cce5h557.aspx) does the trick. Using that you can make new colors.

For example to make red:

```
Color c = Color.FromArgb(255, 0, 0);
```

By the way, "steps through each color" can be a bit much. There are 256(alpha) x 256(red) x 256(green) x 256(blue) colors. That are ***4294967296*** combinations.

Comment: Yeah, which is why I'd rather use the built-in colors. Is there anyway to loop through the fields of a Struct?

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to try it, just for the fun out of it, I would suggest the following.

(You said you are new, so I will do a step-by-step instruction)

We will make a simple example and we will just change the color of the button we will press.

1. Create a form with a button and add a backgroundworker (can be found in the toolbox) to it.
2. Select the backgroundWorker1, change to the events view and double click the DoWork event.
3. You now should get a backgroundWorker1_DoWork method.
4. Add some code:

   ```
   for (int r = 0; r <= 255; r++)
   {
       for (int g = 0; g <= 255; g++)
       {
           for (int b = 0; b <= 255; b++)
           {
               button1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(r, g, b);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
5. In the button you now only have to call

   ```
   backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
   ```

Now you can watch the colors... for a long long time. :)